# Custom attribute not saving nor displaying data in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have manually created an attribute in Magento 2, called xml_feedsource (keyname). It has attribute_id 306.
[image: Admin view of attribute]

I have added it to attribute_set 9:
[image: Added to attribute set]

Then i am programmatically adding a product with code:

```
$product->setXmlFeedsource('used');
```

After saving that, it shows up in in the product grid correctly:
[image: Showing up in product grid]

But, when i open it, it shows empty value:
[image: Empty value]

Even if i go back to the productgrid, it shows "used" as it's meant to be.

When i enter an other value in the field in the admin, like 'test' and save the product, the same situation is still there (showing 'used' in the grid and showing nothing in the product). It actually does not save the updated value of that attribute (it does with other attributes).

I tried to test it in a small read script with:

```
echo "xfs: ".$product->getXmlFeedsource()."\n";
```

It shows no value.

Even if i look in the database in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, it displays the 'used' value for attribute_id 306:
[image: Good value in database]

Checked if the is_user_defined variable would be wrong, but also that seems correctly configured:
[image: Correctly configured is_user_defined]

I am getting zero errors and also checked system.log and exception.log. Nothing to read there either.

I have no idea anymore why this attribute is not handled correctly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has anything to do with the attributeset. If i make a duplicate of the attributeset, it works with that one.